# Arch: Encrypt new HDD with LUKS to be decrypted in boot

Tags: arch-linux, luks, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I installed archlinux with full disk encryption with LUKS for both of my disks a few years back. So when booting, I need to enter the encryption key for each disk. Now I bought a new HDD and I want to encrypt this one too and have it encrypted while booting, the same way as the other two.

I have no clue how to do that anymore. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Have you already read through the Arch LUKS documentation? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa yes. Problem is, that I just want to add a new hdd. and don't setup a full encrypt system. And I am afraid to do something wrong and destory my boot sequence.

Comment: That documentation describes how to use `/etc/cryptab` to unlock LUKS devices during boot using a keyfile. Those are the steps you can use to add an HDD.